# SQL Server 2005 not collecting logins in the log file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, audit, error-log

I am currently running SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition on a Windows 2003 server machine.

I have gone to the properties of the server and confirmed that the Login Auditing is set to both failed and successful logins. For some reason though there is nothing in the logins for fails or successes in the SQL Server logs when I know there have been logins for both.

I have searched out the reason for this and have not been able to come up with anything helpful, so I am hoping that someone here could give me a little direction. This is working on my other SQL Servers, so I know where to look for the results, but there are none there.

Comment: I'm assuming you know logins have happened.  I would do a trace to confirm they're showing up there but they probably are.  Are there any errors in either the SQL or Windows logs that may be related to this?

Answer (score 1):

Per [SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188470.aspx)...

> Changing the audit level requires restarting the service.

Try restarting your SQL Service and then check to see if logins are being properly audited in your Error Log.